# Rspec and non-RestFul routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I am doing homework but I have problem with non-RestFul routes.
My spec is:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MoviesController do
  describe 'searching TMDb' do
    before :each do
      @fake_results = [mock('Movie'), mock('Movie')]
    end
    it 'should call the model method that performs TMDb search' do
      Movie.should_receive(:find_in_tmdb).with('Star Wars').
        and_return(@fake_results)
      get :search_similar_movies, { :search_terms => 'Star Wars' }
    end
  end
end
```

In config/routes.rb I have:

```
resources :movies
  'movies/search_similar_movies/:search_terms'
```

But when I run autotest it gives me error that begins with:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:181:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :action (ArgumentError)
```

It's obvious that something is wrong is config/routes.rb. How to solve this?

Comment: Have a look at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes

Comment: @pjumble, it works. Do I need to specify param :search_term somewhere in routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route should be something like

```
resources :movies do
    get 'search_similar_movies', :on => :collection
end
```

or

`match 'movies/search_similar_movies/:search_terms' => 'movies#search_similar_movies', :via => :get`